# How to run TestNG.xml file through Terminal

Tags: selenium, terminal, testng

I am using MacOS and trying to execute my selenium code through Terminal, but not able to execute.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can't , you need to run it through Maven and than you can do it Through the Terminal

Comment: Can you help me with the steps please.

Comment: In big steps (because its more than that) you need to install Maven, than install surefire plugin than add the XML of testNG to it, than you can run the plugin from command / terminal and use the XML